# How can we set permissions to a specific channel (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord, permissions, discord.py

I've tried to set the permissions on a specific channel (defined before) but it doesn't work. I want the channel to be a specific one and not one based on `await ctx.channel.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)`

Here's my line that I use to set the permission that doesn't work. Channel is the ID of a specific channel:

```
await channel.set_permissions(role, overwrite = None, send_messages=False)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the channel object with the id before you try to call `set_permissions`. Also, you can't mix `overwrite` with other permission kwargs.

`channel` being the channel's id:

```
channel_obj = bot.get_channel(channel)
await channel_obj.set_permissions(role, send_messages=False)
```

Instead of `overwrite=None, send_messages=False` you can do:

```
overwrite = discord.PermissionOverwrite()
overwrite.send_messages = False
await channel_obj.set_permissions(role, overwrite=overwrite)
```